# Null reference error while inflating a textview

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

I'm adding a textview as a header to a listview, in a Xamarin Android app.
Following the instructions in ericosg's answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view/20475821#20475821), I put the textview in a separate axml file, and then tried to add it as a header to my list view.

Running the app gets the following error at the line where the activity tries to inflate the textview:

```
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Exception of type 'Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException' was thrown.
.
.
.
[MonoDroid]   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
[MonoDroid] android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050006 type #0x12 is not valid
[MonoDroid]     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2250)  
etc.
```

Here is my code:

In the Activity .cs file:

```
myListView = FindViewById<ListView>(MyApp.Resource.Id.MyList);

        Android.Views.View myHeader = 
            this.LayoutInflater.Inflate(MyApp.Resource.Id.QuestionText, myListView);

        myListView.AddHeaderView(myHeader);
```

ListView definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/MyList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Header definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/QuestionText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@+id/MyImage" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

You are attempting to inflate an ID resource instead of a layout:

```
 Android.Views.View myHeader = this.LayoutInflater.Inflate(MyApp.Resource.Id.QuestionText, myListView);
```

The `Inflate` call for `LayoutInflater` only accepts `Resource.Layout` elements. Change it to:

```
Android.Views.View myHeader = this.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Header, myListView);
```

Secondly, in your Header.xml layout file, `TextView android:drawableTop` does not accept id references so it will throw an `InflateException` when the `LayoutInflator` attempts to build the layout.

[From the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableTop):

> android:drawableTop
>
> The drawable to be drawn above the text.
>
> May be a reference to another resource, in the form "@[+][package:]type:name" or to a theme attribute in the form "?[package:][type:]name".
>
> May be a color value, in the form of "#rgb", "#argb", "#rrggbb", or "#aarrggbb".

Change this to either a reference to a valid color or drawable (@drawable/MyImage) or an inline color declartion (#fff).

Lastly, you can't add child views or header views to the ListView without using an adapter:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7978427/1099111
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7978427/1099111

Consider re-reading the [Xamarin docs for ListViews and Adapters](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/) to better understand the subject.

Comment: Thank you.  It will take me a little while to absorb this info, so I will be back later.  I do find the Xamarin docs hard, they always seem to assume knowledge I don't have.

Comment: Stick with it S List, it *does* take a little while to learn it all. The difficultly curve is tough because it covers multiple frameworks, languages and operating systems; we've all been there! Just keep chipping at it :)

Comment: I enclosed the TextView of the header in a RelativeLayout, and created an id for it.  Then I passed this id to the Inflater.  Also, I separated the text and the image into separate headers.  I already have an adapter.

Comment: After doing these changes, I got an "invalidOperation" exception, which was solved by Clint's answer from this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306324/unable-to-use-layoutinflater-in-custom-adapter/6419586#6419586

Comment: Inflating and adding the headers now works.  Thank you very much for this great answer, and your kind words of encouragement.